# How to assign IPs in server interfaces when connected to two similar routers

Tags: networking, router, ipv4, network-interface, private-network

I need to connect two similar routers with the IPs `192.160.2.4/24`  and `192.160.2.6/24` (in the same `192.160.2.0/24` network) to 2 server interfaces (ports) in the same server as shown in the image.

[image]

However, I cannot understand how to assign the IPs to the server interfaces.

After some googling, I now think that the server interfaces are bonded into a single virtual interface, and a single IP is assigned by the server OS. But I am not sure how the traffic flow and ARP work here, and whether redundancy mechanism is used as well.

How would the traffic flow to and from the server in the DLL and Network layers? Any help would be appreciated to understand how this configuration works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends more on what is on the other side of each router. Are they both gateways to the internet? Why are you doing this? Without a better understanding of that we can’t really help you. In regards to addressing you simply give the server a unique IP on each interface. The question here is about “routing” not addressing.

Comment: One doesn't *connect* to a router, but rather *uses* it, via URLs that go through the router. This then depends on how your network and routing table are setup. You can't use two routers to access the same resource.